# UIImage picker controller works only the second time through

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller

Hi I have had a working UIImage picker controller and suddenly it now only shows the photo on the view the second time i select USE.

Here's the code

header

```
@interface UpdatePriceView : UIViewController  <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate > {

    UIImagePickerController *myPhoto;


}



@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImagePickerController *myPhoto;
```

implementation

```
- (IBAction)Photo{

    self.myPhoto = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.myPhoto.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    self.myPhoto.delegate = self;
    self.myPhoto.allowsEditing = NO;
    self.myPhoto.showsCameraControls = YES;

    [self presentModalViewController:self.myPhoto animated:YES];

}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSLog(@"didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method");

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    NSLog (@"Image = %@",image);


    [self.PhotoView setImage:image];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

What am i Doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do that:

```m
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    self.photo = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [picker release];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    imgView.image = photo;
}
```